# Sequelize - how to handle dynamic data in migration script

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize, mysql and nodejs for backend development.

I have a `question` table to store the questions, which is not finalized yet.

Therefore, anytime I want to add new questions, I will run below command.

Update migration script `20210610080725-add-questions` > `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate:undo:all` > `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`

I know that the most correct way to add questions, is to create new migration script and run it, but I want a single source of `questions`. If I create new migration script, there are more than one files of `questions`, which make me difficult to trace the questions.

Is there any recommended way to solve this problem?

migrations/scripts/20210610080725-add-questions

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('question', [
      {
        id: "440f46bd-bc41-4ed1-866c-17712366a380",
        questionText: 'xxxxx',
      },
      {
        id: "f357fa93-d18e-490b-9baf-c1f6b3e582e3",
        questionText: 'yyyyy'
      },
      ...
    ]);
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('question', null, {});
  }
};
```

Comment: Database migrations are more for changing the structure of your database as opposed to adding new data. Applications usually have an admin interface where master data can be added - such as new questions and thus your database will be your golden source of the questions. Your data can then be backed up and restored (even to a different mysql instance) if necessary.

Comment: @Shadow no admin interface will be created. If updating the questions, I will add it manually. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Then you are not following the recommended approach in the first place. I would only use migrations for adding questions, if you want to be able to easily remove a set of questions you added. Otherwise, just use an sql script or a text file.

Comment: @Shadow because when upating the questions as you suggust, i need to manually run sql on dev, uat and prod, it might be easy to have manual error

Comment: Unless you run the wrong sql script, no, you cannot have manual errors. Ideally, you should not be running sql scripts manually on production, though. And I maintain that you are facing this issue because you are not following the recommended path of using your database as the golden source of you data.